# Writing a Vlookup in VBA that can search for large numbers

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to retun the product name based on it's ID. Integer only works as a data type for smaller numbers. The code works for shorter ID numbers Using Long does not solve the issue. What do I need to change?

**Here is my VBA code:**

```
Function ProdName(webID As Long)

Dim name As String

Set book2 = Workbooks("PERSONAL.xlsb")

Set r2 = book2.Sheets(2).Range("$A:$B")

name = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(webID, r2, 2, False)

ProdName = name

End Function
```

And here is the table I'm looking into:

[image: screenshot]

I also tried playing around with data types to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `Variant`..

Comment: Changed to : Function ProdName(webID As Variant) but still getting the "#NUM!" error. Anything else I need to change?

Comment: Works for me with your sample data, even with `Long`, but I'd use `Variant` still.

Comment: That's very strange. Should I try creating a new module? Are you using a module or class module?

Comment: I would try debugging by calling the function from within a `Sub` instead of as a UDF.

Comment: Thanks. Somewhat new to this. How does one do that?

Comment: `Sub Test`, `Debug.Print ProdName(123456789)`, `End Sub`.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, really appreciate it. Where would I place that sub test? I haven't used that before. Like I said, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Right underneath your `Function` code.

Comment: Now put the cursor in `Sub Test()` and hit F5 to run it.

Comment: Ok, I added the sub test under "end function" and ran it. Does it need to be before end function? Not seeing a change in my error.

Comment: Now hit `Ctrl+G` to bring up the Immediate Window, and check the result.

Comment: Progress! I'm getting the correct result: "Test name1". Now how do I get it to work in the worksheet, where it still returns "#NUM!"?

Comment: Hmmm. That's weird. Not sure why it isn't working when called from the cell as a User Defined Function (UDF).

Comment: On a hunch, I copied the code into a new module and called the function ProdName2 using Variant. Now it works! Thank you so much for your help!